# easiest way to refactor code from Objective-C to java?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, eclipse, xcode

I am an iOS developer and my entire career, to date has been spent using Xcode, along with Objective-C and C code, to write apps for the Apple app store. I would like to refactor my code to java and/or xml using Eclipse and try getting a few of my existing apps on Google play.

I understand that even though both languages are object-oriented, one (Objective-C) is compiled and the other (java) is interpreted. Does this present any barriers to essentially refactoring the code file by file, line by line?? What about the C functions? Will they work in Eclipse?

Is there some kind of translator that will automatically convert Objective-C to java, or translate Xcode files to Eclipse files????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android and iOS platforms are significantly different, so trying to port an app, line-by-line is going to produce an app of very low quality. To be honest, it's not really feasible because of the **vast** differences in APIs. The more "interesting" the app (in other words, the more it does), the more trouble there is in porting it. Beyond API differences, there are fundamental differences in the philosophies of the two platforms that will cause major re-design of functionality, not just code.

That isn't saying that apps should not be written for both platforms. Many apps are indeed available for both. But it's not a trivial or automated effort unless you started out with a cross-platform mobile development framework (for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809740/can-i-code-iphone-apps-using-eclipse/26809968#26809968)). Moving an app to a new platform requires redesigning the app to fit that platform before you even start looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can translate a file in Objective C to Java line by line using this framework in your Android Project:

http://github.com/rcmcastro/cocoatouch-for-android

But you will need to create the UI, because it's totally different. But the logic, the architecture and everything else will be the same and will work just translating the files and run the app.