# Can I code iPhone apps using Eclipse?

Tags: ios, iphone, eclipse

As you can probably guess, my knowledge of coding is *very* limited. Nonetheless, I do know a little Java. I have Eclipse and was wondering if I could use it to code for iOS iPhone/iPad applications. I know that I would almost certainly have to use a language other than Java, but I'm clueless as to what packages or plugins I would need to install in Eclipse to use it to code for iOS. If you guys could answer this question in extreme detail or link me to a very good sequence of video tutorials, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can!

If you can live with coding ActionScript, which should be easy to learn with a Java background, you can use Eclipse & AIR to code for iOS (and Android at the same time)

Some resources:
    http://flex.apache.org/
    http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashruntimes/
    http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/
    http://flashdaily.net/

Be aware that many apps in the store have been build on this platform, and the community is pretty alive and supportive.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, "not natively."

Apple pretty much restricts "native" iOS development to XCode which, as @Bob said in his answer, is only available for OS X. So that means no Eclipse or Java-based development. However, there are several cross-platform development frameworks and tools that work to varying degrees of quality. Here are a few, in no particular order:

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
- [Corona](http://coronalabs.com/)
- Adobe AIR (see answer by @dogsgod)

There are others, but those are ones that I've at least heard of and might have tried a little bit. Some, like Appcelerator, have IDEs built on Eclipse, so at least the dev environment would be familiar.

Answer (score 1):

IOS apps are written in Objective-C or Swift using XCode.  (This also means you'll need a Mac to do so. XCode is only available for OSX.)

So unfortunately this means the answer to your question is no.  You cannot use Eclipse to write an iOS app.

Comment: So-o-o-o-o, is this forum answer flat out wrong? http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/607493-Is-there-a-Windows-equivalent-to-XCode

Comment: I don't see anything in that thread about iOS development.  Not sure what in there seems to contradict what I've said.

Comment: Woops, I thought the forum was talking about iOS apps. Also, it looks as if there's a way to code for iOS apps using Eclipse if you code in ActionScript.